# How many times does the function run?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was given this...

```
for i=1 to 8
    for j=9 to 19
         for k=24 to 33
             questionfunction(i,j,k)
          end
    end
end
```

How many times will the function in in innermost loop be called? I don't even know where to begin on this. My test guess would be 7+10+9 because that's the total number of times the loops run but I don't really know

Comment: Try "hand executing" a loop like for i=1 to 3, for j=1 to 3, func(i,j), end, end. You should see the pattern that nested loops create.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean hand execute? That loop situation you described confuses me because there is nothing indicating anything happening in the loop..im just confused

Comment: I can't indent here, but there is something, inside the second loop there is a call to a function. Just count each time that you call func along the way. (Alternately, you could have the counting be what the program does, by adding 1 to a variable at each stage of the loop.)

Comment: So by the time the I is done, the j has 3 left, and when that is done the k is done so the function ends at 10?

Comment: You do the whole double loop over (j,k) for each value of i.

Comment: @DestinyCoots No, that's not how it works. Since the for loops are inside each other, the inner one will loop for *each* value of the outer loop. So, when $i$ takes the value of $1$, and $j$ the value of $9$, $ k$ takes on the values of $24$ through $33$ ... which results in $10$ function calls (not $9$), but then $j$ will taken on the value of $10$, and $k$ will once again loop through $24$ through $33$, etc. And when $j$ has taken on its last value of$19$, and $k$ has yet again from $24$ to $33$, $i$ will take the value of $2$, and now $j$ will start back at $9$, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

8*11*10

See it this way

First for loop called i=1 -> inner one called j=9 --> third one called k=24, finally the function is called with values (1,9,24)

This will be the orders now

(1,9,24),
(1,9,25),
(1,9,26),(1,9,27),
......,
(1,9,33) --> 10 times

Now innermost for condition is false, so the one iteration of second for loop is complete.

j=10 --> another 10 times

So this will go on till 11*10 times and one iteration of the outermost for loop will be completed.

This will go on for 8 times (as i = 1 to 8)

So the answer is 8*11*10

Comment: Why did you stop at $32$ rather than $33$?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Matlab for loops were not inclusive